# Object Allocation and String.format() on Android

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, hprof

`String.format()` creates a `StringBuilder` object each time it is invoked.

Given concerns over object allocation and garbage collection on Android, does it make sense to replace `String.format` operations (particularly in Logging operations) with some kind of reusable formatter and an object pool?

Is there an existing library for this?

Comment: do you mean beyond using the res/string.xml with things like   '<string name="sPlaylistTracksTotalTime">"%1$s track(s)/ total time: %2$s"</string>'  ?

Comment: formating code parts, placed commas, etc..

Comment: res.getString(id, args...) is just a wrapper around String.format(str, args...) the problem I see is that String.format() itself creates at least two objects. (StringBuilder and Formatter).

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks - I was hoping that using the xml might result in some performance-friendly precompile effect.